# Editing QTreeView items when each tier have different item type

Tags: qt, datamapper

I'm doing a character animation editor.

My character is represented in a QTreeView like this

- Character

  - Animation 0

    - Frame 0
    - Frame 1
    - Frame 2
  - Animation 1

    - Frame 3
    - Frame 4
    - Frame 5

And etc.

There is a basic abstract `Item` class that `Character`, `Animation` and `Frame` inherits from.

The restrictions are:

- `Character` items can have any number of ONLY `Animation` items
- `Animations` items can have any number of ONLY `Frame` items
- `Frame` items can not have any children

Now, everything that inherits from `Item` have a name. Then every type of item adds its own attributes (`Animation` can have Wrap mode, FPS; `Frame` can have duration).

So each level of the tree has different data set.

Now I want to add another widget that allows editing the data of each `Item`. The widget will be broken into 3 parts (sections): Data related to character, data related to animation and data related to frame.
When the user selects an item in the tree, the widget will autofill itself according to the following rules:

1. If selected item is `Character` => Fill only character section
2. If selected item is `Animation` => Fill the animation section + do step `1` with the character that is the parent of this animation
3. If selected item is `Frame` => Fill the frame section + do step `2` with the animation that is the parent of this frame

I can distinguish between selected items (I can tell if it either Character, Animation of Frame). I can access the parent item from the selected child.

My problem is that I don't know how to map the data between my tree's model and the editing widgets. I looked into QDataWidgetMapper but it does not help, it looks like it works on models that have the same item, while my model have different items per level.

I might have a major design flaw, or I simply don't know how to achieve what I'm trying to implement.

I'd like some guidance.

P.S.

Here is an image of the main screen hierarchy and the 3 sections
[image: dmut hierarchy and section editing]

Comment: Show some code. `QDataWidgetMapper` is solution.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I don't have code with `QDataWidgetMapper` I just don't know how to use it here. It maps item to widgets, but my item is different on each level therefore I don't know what I should map. I'm not sure what code you want to see, but everything is here https://github.com/skwee/dmut/tree/master/src Relevant files are Item, Character, Animation, Frame, CharacterHierarchyWidget and CharacterModel

Comment: P.S. I'm not looking for a code solution. Guidance to how to use QDataWidgetMapper might be nice, because I do fell this is the solution, but from what I understand QDataWidgetMapper works if all items are the same, my items however have different columns and column count depending on the tree level.

Comment: You shoud remap widget each time, when selection changed. According to your logic.

Comment: Ok this sounds great! It will solve the problem of selected different levels and displaying their attributes. However lets say I've selected `Frame`, remapped the data mapper to suits `Frame` item. How I can show also `Frame`'s parent `Animation` and `Animations`'s parent `Character`? At this scenario I want to be able to edit 3 different Items using one QDataWidgetMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary, from comments:

1. Use QDataWidgetMapper for data mapping. You may create 3 mapping. For each frame.
2. Use QStackedWidget for editor frames
3. On each selection change - set mapping and show necessary widget.

Comment: Not sure I got you, but let me try that in code. Ill come back to update the question.

Comment: Ok, I did like you said. I used 3 QDataWidgetMappers each responsible for its own Widget. However on each selection I needed to change the rootIndex of the mappers in order to make this work. Thanks for guidance!